# How to wait promises ad push data to array in forEach loop [react]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, promise, google-cloud-firestore

So i want to use this effect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    return db.collection('users').orderBy('lastName').onSnapshot(snap => {
       const usersArray = []
       snap.forEach( async doc => {
         const user = doc.data()
         if(user.manager) {
            await Promise.all([
            db.collection('users').doc(user.manager).get(),
            db.collection('roles').doc(user.profile).get()
          ]).then(resp => {
                    const manager = resp[0].data()
                    const role = resp[1].data()
                    usersArray.push({
                      id: doc.id,
                      ...user,
                      manager: `${manager.lastName} ${manager.name} ${manager.middleName}`,
                      role: role.profile
                    })
                  })
         } else {
           await db
             .collection('roles')
             .doc(user.profile)
             .get().then(resp => {
              const role = resp.data()
              usersArray.push({
                id: doc.id,
                ...user,
                role: role.profile
              })
             })
         }
         usersArray.push({test: 'test'})
       })
       console.log(usersArray)
       setAgents(usersArray)
     })
   }, [])
```

Here i'm getting list of users, then i want to get for each user data about their role in system and their managers, and update user object and push to array. After that i want to render it. But now, i'm always getting empty array. In `console.log` of `.then` blocks data is correct.

Please help to get right code

[image]

Comment: You could create an array of promises and use `Promise.all` to resolve all promises

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the `console.log` part of the code is synchronously executed before any of the data is actually written into the array. `forEach` array property creates a non blocking callback independent of the main execution. If you want to make sure that every item in `snap` is processed before executing the `console.log` I recommend using `map` instead, map has a unique property of actually returning a value (as opposed to foreach). In this case that return value would be callback promise. You could just await the result of the map to make sure all items were written into the array or even better return the actual items inside of the callback.

here is example code (for simplicity i removed the `usersArray.push({test: 'test'})` which i assume is unneeded)

```
useEffect(() => {
    return db.collection('users').orderBy('lastName').onSnapshot(snap => {
        const usersArrayPromise = snap.documents.map(doc => {
            const user = doc.data();

            if (user.manager) return Promise.all([
                db.collection('users').doc(user.manager).get(),
                db.collection('roles').doc(user.profile).get()
            ]).then(resp => {
                const manager = resp[0].data();
                const role = resp[1].data();
                return {id: doc.id, ...user, manager: `${manager.lastName} ${manager.name} ${manager.middleName}`, role: role.profile};
            });

            return db.collection('roles')
                .doc(user.profile)
                .get().then(resp => {
                    const role = resp.data();
                    return {id: doc.id, ...user, role: role.profile}
                })
        });
        Promise.all(usersArrayPromise).then(usersArray => {
            console.log(usersArray)
            setAgents(usersArray)
        });
    })
}, []);
```

Please take a note of the fact that firebase QuerySnapshot isn't an actual array but implements array like `forEach` property, if you want to use map you would do `snap.documents.map`.

Comment: Getting error snap.map is not a function. We are working with firebase. snap is an object

Comment: if `snap.forEach` is a function then `snap.map` is one as well, this error seems unrelated to the question. You can try to do `Array.from(snap).map` but i don't see how would that be needed

Comment: if you are using `firebase` try `snap.documents.map` instead

Comment: your advice helped, but it still getting an empty array and console.log

Comment: sorry, Array.from(snap).map - that's getting empty array

Comment: if you are using firebase try snap.documents.map instead - this approach works! Thanks allot!